# Custom WordPress Shortcode Parameters

Tags: wordpress, parameters, shortcode

I'm working on a custom blog that has several different pieces of content that can go into a blog post. Each of these pieces are custom styled divs, and I'm a little concerned about having the client input multiple lines of code each time they want to use a pull-quote or an aside image.

I'd like to create a few custom shortcodes, but I'm afraid I don't know where to start. For example, the HTML for a pull quote looks like this:

```
<!--SIDE QUOTE-->
        <div class="inline-side quote cf:before cf:after cf">
            <h5>
                <span class="pull-quote-quotes">&#8220;</span>
                    REPLACE ME
                <span class="pull-quote-quotes">&#8221;</span>
            </h5>
        </div>
```

I would like for this to be a shortcode while allowing the user to type custom text where it says "REPLACE ME."

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

```
function wpse_inline_side_quote( $atts, $content = "" ) {
    return 
        '<div class="inline-side quote cf:before cf:after cf">
            <h5>
                <span class="pull-quote-quotes">&#8220;</span>
                ' . $content . '
                <span class="pull-quote-quotes">&#8221;</span>
            </h5>
        </div>';
}
add_shortcode( 'inline-quote', 'wpse_inline_side_quote' );
```

Using the example above the shortcode would be [inline-quote]REPLACE ME[/inline-quote]

Comment: Thank you, Nathan! Is it possible to add multiple parameters? For example, if I wanted to allow the user to add an image, caption, and link?

Comment: Yes that would be possible using shortcode attributes.Take a look at http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_shortcode#Examples for more info